# Is it possible to host and link to PDF's in the developer portal?

Tags: azure-api-management

As the title says, I am interested in adding PDF files as media and linking to them.

When I try this, the link tries to open the PDF as a page and fails.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a pdf file and create a link in the text editor.

1. in the Text editor select text to be a link on pdf file
2. in the Text editor toolbar select the link icon 
   [image: Text editor tool bar]
3. Select media and upload pdf file

[image]

4. Select uploaded pdf file (you have an option to open in the same window or in a new one)
5. Save and publish

Comment: That does not work, the portal tries to open it as a page and fails

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Igor. It turns out that it does work, but not if you have spaces in the filename.

Comment: Yes, this space problem in files names is a known issue and will be fixed with the next release